# Showing relation for raising and lowering operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I found this task in an older exam of quantum mechanics and it was about the harmonic oscillator and thought it would be a good practice for myself. The task goes as:

$\text{The normed eigenstates}\ |n\rangle \ \text{can be calculated from the zero state as:}$
$$|n\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} (a^{\dagger})^n|0\rangle$$
$\text{Use this relation to show the following:}$
$$a^{\dagger}|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle \quad , \quad a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle $$
I think I showed the first one:

$\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}(a^{\dagger})^{n+1}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a^{\dagger})^{n+1}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}a^{\dagger}(a^{\dagger})^{n}|0\rangle=a^{\dagger}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a^{\dagger})^{n}|0\rangle=a^{\dagger}|n\rangle$

But I don't know how to show the second relation. Any advice tip/solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Take the conjugate of the first equation:
$$
\langle n \mid\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\langle 0 \mid\ a^n
$$
and use the same logic as with the first part.

Comment: I totally forgot that property. I got it now.